# Pure functional programming on android

Tags: android, functional-programming, jvm

Are there any advancements in this area? I want to be able to write purely functional code on Android in Haskell or similar languages. I've tried some examples with Scala but it seems to be a pain to get started. Are there any other functional JVM languages which I can use to write Android applications?

Edit: functional languages that write native android applications. My mistake about the JVM.

Comment: I think Clojure also runs on the JVM. I don't have experience with it.

Comment: *"It seems to be a pain to get started"* Most functional programming languages have a steep learning curve. For this to be on-topic, I think you should instead ask about how to make X language work in Android. The JVM isn't used by Android, so that's the most likely pain point. Asking people to recommend programming languages is opinion-based.

Comment: I'm talking more about gradle builds etc. And sometimes the examples that exist are [single activity hello world programs](https://github.com/neurocyte/android-haskell-activity). I'm asking more for maturity, tooling and stuff

Comment: scala is not a pain to get started. -- get sbt, add the appropriate plugin, go

Comment: If this is still relevant, Eta is used with Android already https://github.com/Jyothsnasrinivas/eta-android-2048 . It also has a Gradle Plugin and much more, a lot has occurred this last year, check the site!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I doubt that you can find anything mature for writing Haskell-like code for Android. You do need to implement Java abstractions which are required by Android API (implement activity, etc.).

But if you really want to write for Android in a purely functional style you can try to implement your business logic in a pure functional language that compiles to JVM and call it from your Java classes. That approach would be much simpler than trying to implement it entirely in pure functional style.

As your language choice, you can try

- [Frege](https://github.com/Frege/frege), it even has a library for android - [froid](https://github.com/mchav/froid)
- [Eta lang](http://eta-lang.org/), it is very new and probably nobody has tried to use it for Android yet

Comment: Are there any applications built with froid?

Comment: @user3574294 I don't know. I reckon most android application aren't open source, but you can try to search for froid usages on Github. In you are looking for maturity and ML-style isn't a requirement, you can try Kotlin+Anko. It will allow you to write functional code but without any guarantees about purity.

Answer (score 7):

I you want a painless solution in terms of Gradle builds etc., you have only two options: Java and **Kotlin**, of which of course you should choose **Kotlin** ;)

[**Kotlin**](https://kotlinlang.org/) has most of the things you need to write in functional style:

- functions as first class citizen
- higher-order functions
- immutable collections
- `var` and `val` like in Scala
- `if-else` as a statement
- elements of pattern matching (`where` statement)
- tail recursion
- and more...

If you also include [**funKTionale**](https://github.com/MarioAriasC/funKTionale) and [**kotlinx.collections.immutable**](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.collections.immutable), you'll have all the functional goodies like: `Option`, `Try`, currying, memoization, persistent data structures and so on...

To start with Kotlin just install the latest [**Android Studio 3 Preview**](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html), which already has built-in Kotlin support.

BTW, don't be so polarized into "pure" functional ;) After all, being 100% "pure" means no side-effects, which means your app can't interact with the user ;)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Why is there a downvote on this comment? I think it deserves more positive vote instead

Comment: @Derekyy because it is not functional. It's like saying you can develop Android App in C++ purely functional since C++ also supports functional programming

Answer (score 3):

I've never tried it personally, but you can do F# programming using Xamarin.Android (and, I believe, with Xamarin Forms too). You can see the guide [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/fsharp/fsharp_support_overview/). (It also includes sample code).

As some background, F# is the .NET Framework's functional language. It is derived from ML; in fact, many ML scripts can be compiled almost "directly" as F# (with the caveat that you may have to do some renaming because F# has some additional keywords that ML doesn't have in order to support several .NET-specific extensions).

Xamarin allows for native development for Android, iOS, and Windows phone. Xamarin Forms allows for a single code-base for all three platforms (it's a competitor to Ionic).

One more quick point: Android does *not* use the JVM, even if you're writing apps in Java. (In fact, Android [does not even support all Java 8 features](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html) yet). Through Android 4.4 it used [Dalvik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)); after that, it started using [Android Runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Runtime).

You could also try using a JVM language like Scala to create a JAR file and create a bindings library for it.

Please also note that you'll end up using at least somewhat of a mixed paradigm - for example, things like Activities are objects, and the XML files used to define an Android screen is, for all practical purposes, declarative. **Edit:** This last point is slightly debatable - see the comments.

One final possibility: I haven't checked this out too closely, but try also [this link](http://scala-android.org/) for a site claiming you can do Scala in Android.

Comment: Activities may be objects, but that doesn't necessarily mean the solution will be object-oriented.

Comment: @4castle I'm not sure I follow - I think that it would mean that you were, at a minimum, using multiple paradigms (functional, declarative, and object-oriented).

Comment: I'm saying that object-oriented programming is a paradigm. Objects are a data type. Just as an object-oriented programming language can use functions without doing any functional programming, a functional programming language can use objects without being object-oriented. The paradigms are defined by more than just their primary data type.

Comment: Another source for using F# on Android (either via Xamarin or HTML5 apps) http://fsharp.org/use/android/

Answer (score 1):

Between *Pure functional* and *Java*, there is a way which is IMO **Pragmatic functional**. For instance *Redux* achieves that in the *React* arena.

My goal is to write an app (Activity) having an immutable state that advanced as a result of interactions is functional.
In the browser you can see that done with [*elm*](http://elm-lang.org/) (Haskel like language which is also web platform)

Since we want an Android app, I opened the **Android Studio** used the wizard to create and app with Navigaton Drawer Action bar (with Drawer, FloatingActionBar), 
Then converted it to use *Elm concepts* of immutable model functional approach into a working POC based on a small ElmBase class and idioms. 
The code is written in **Kotlin** (JetBrains tool of choice for the JVM).

You can find the app at my GitHub https://github.com/saffih/ElmDroid The sweet spot of that approach is that it leverages Kotlin being strongly typed and the editor does code completions very well,
making lot's of the code completed for me in a way I have never seen before - amazing experience (But it require using idioms like the *sealed* class and *when* properly).